# MVC3 Navigation, browser positionin g

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, navigation, positioning

I have a C#.NET MVC3 web app.  I have a View that has a List of Models.  This list can be long, requiring the user to scroll down on the View.  When selecting one of the models in the View to Edit, the user is taken to the Edit View.  After submitting the Edit View, the user is redirected back to the List View.  However, the List View is now displaying back at the top of the list.  How can I redirect the user back to the same position in the List View where they clicked the Edit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably be better suited using a modal popup dialog to edit the data, rather than navigating to another page.

While it's possible to do what you want, it's a pain.  You would have to get the scroll location via javascript, save it to a hidden field, post that to your edit page, along with record number and anything else, then re-post it back to your original page when you return, then read the post value and scroll to it via javascript.

All that is avoided if you just use a modal edit dialog, then when the dialog goes away the page is still in the same place.

Comment: @MikeTWebb - Another option is to do in-place editing in the row.  If that works for you, that's even better.